# Facebook debugger is caching different IP addresses for same domain

Tags: redirects, https, facebook, cache

I have problem with Facebook debugger, I tried to scrape domains few times, and I got strange results.

Facebook debugger is caching different IP addresses for the same domain. I saw a few different IP addresses in half hour of scraping.

- 158.69.39.225
- 185.80.69.2
- 51.15.154.158

Sites is located on 192.99.106.21. (ping)

I suspect that the problem is dedicated to the http and https protocol or with DNS because debugger showing crazy **redirect cycles.**

- Input URL    >   https://kurir.rs/
- 301 HTTP Redirect    >   http://www.kurir.rs/
- 301 HTTP Redirect    >   https://www.kurir.rs/

For example:

- When I scrape http://kurir.rs/ i got 158.69.39.235
- When I scrape https://kurir.rs/  51.15.154.158
- There is no scheme for this, I also got 185.80.69.2 few times.

Espreso.rs and kurir.rs is websites with a lot of traffic. I doubt that that affecting our FB organic reach, which is serious problem for us.

I already contacted them but I want to hear another opinion.

Comment: It isn't unusual for high traffic sites to have multiple IP addresses. And `www.kurir.ws` and `kurir.ws` resolve to different IPs for me, so that might explain part of what you are seeing. "I doubt that that affecting our FB organic reach" doesn't make much sense, so perhaps you could clarify what the problem is.